# Unable to read Java File from JSF

Tags: java, jsf

The directory structure of my application is as follows:-

```
My App
++++++ src
++++++++com
++++++++++readProp.java
++++++++resource
++++++++++message.properties
```

I am trying to read the file as follows:-

```
public Static final string FilePath="resource.message.properties"
```

Here the code to read the file. I tried using the following two techniques but to no use...

```
File accountPropertiesFile = new File(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() 
.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() 
+ FilePath); 

properties.load(externalContext.getResourceAsStream(FilePath));
```

But none yeild any sucess while reading through the Bean class. please help...

Answer (score 1):

Your properties file is in the classpath. The `java.io.File` only understands the local disk file system structure. This is not going to work. You need to get it straight from the classpath by the classloader.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/resources/messages.properties");

if (input != null) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(input);
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but you should try using slashes instead of periods, since they're stored as actual folders in the filesystem.