# Java use pdfviewer to display file present in resource folder

Tags: java, pdf, resources, filenotfoundexception

I have java web app. I am using `ANT` to build the application. I have a file in the resources folder. I want to open that file using a pdfViewer. The frame of the pdf viewer is getting launched. But I am not able to access the file present in the resources folder. here is my code.

```
final String fileName="Installation.pdf"; 

int pagenum = 0;
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile (new File(fileName), "r");
FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel ();
ByteBuffer buf = fc.map (FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size ());
PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile (buf);
```

[image]
I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`. The main problem is that I am not able to locate the file in the resources folder. What Please help.

The above is working properly when I run it as a stand alone java application.

Comment: Can you provide your directory hierarchy?

Comment: By "pdfViewer" DYM mean a specific API, or do you simply mean a generic viewer for PDF documents?

Comment: You could simply *open* the file instead of launching pdf viewer. People usually have correct system association for pdf files. Here is the relevant answer: [Using Ant, how do I open a file in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6597772/772981)

Comment: Now I see this question is not about ant, so I'm removing this tag. What built the application should not matter, only the contents of jar and classpath.

Comment: Is this question really about pdf? If you get the exception in `new File` call, why asking about pdfs? Perhaps this is a duplicate of: [Getting the inputstream from a classpath resource (XML file)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/793213/772981).

Comment: @Jarekczek This file is goin to be on a client's server and it would be btr to have it in our war file.

Comment: @CAMOBAP I have updated the file structure.

Comment: The main problem I am facing is that I am not able to locate the file in the resources folder

Comment: Are you tried use `new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/Installation.pdf"))` instead of `new File(fileName), "r"`?

Comment: @CAMOBAP  I have tried it. It gives me a nullPointerException

Comment: @CAMOBAP  I am using JSF

Comment: Have you seen [this solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319689/unable-to-read-java-file-from-jsf)?

Comment: @CAMOBAP Tht comes as inputstream. I need a file. anyway I can do tht?

Comment: You can use `URL url = classLoader.getResource(...)` instead of `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(...)`, and after you get the `URL` you can create `File` from it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19140/discussion-between-camobap-and-droidme)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("/resources/Installation.pdf");

if (url != null) {

    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile (new File(url), "r");

        ...

    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this issue?